# C++ std::string and string

Tags: c++, string, std, stdstring

I don't suppose anyone tell me whats the difference between using the std::string and just the string data type in C++??

In what situation should the std::string should be used over the standard string??

Thanks.

Comment: what standard string data type? are you talking about `char *`?

Comment: I mean string by itself. Like when I declaring a varible 'string name'... If that makes any sense?? :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're both the same type. `std::string` specifies the namespace, while `string` only makes sense if a `using namespace std;` or `using std::string` statement is used. So it doesn't make any difference what you use (as long as you're consistent).

If you're talking about the string literals (such as `"hello"`), then they're of type `const char []`, that implicitly decays in a `const char *`. `std::string` has a non-`explicit` constructor that takes a `const char *`, this allowing implicit conversion from `const char *` to `std::string`. The opposite operation can be done with the  `std::string::c_str()` method.

If you're looking for a reason to use `std::string` instead of `const char *`, then I guess my answer would be "as much as you can".

Comment: Technically, the string literal `"hello"` is of type `const char[6]`.

Answer (score 4):

These are likely the same thing within your program.  The "standard" string resides within the "std" namespace.  If you are "using std::string;"  or "using namespace std;" within the module, then they are equivalent.  If you aren't specifying a "using" statement, then you are required to provide the namespace of the object.  It's preferable to not provide "using" statements within the header file and therefore you will typically see namespace resolution/specifiers on objects.  (i.e.  std::vector, mynamespace::myclass, etc.).  The use of "using" is more common in implementation files where they won't affect other files as they would if specified in a header file.

It's possible to use a string object from another provider.  In this case the provider would/should have their string object implementation in their own namespace and you would need to declare which string object you were using.

So:

```
File: stdString.cpp
-------------
#include <string>
#include "providerx/string.h"

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
   string x;          // Using string object provided by the C++ standard library
   std::string y;     // Again, using C++ standard lib string
   providerx::string  // Using string object defined within the providerx namespace
}




File: providerString.cpp
-------------------
#include "providerx/string.h"

using providerX::string;

void foo()
{
    string x;   // Using providerx string object
}
```

Comment: I like the explanation of when each form is likely to be appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have `using namespace std` somewhere in your code.  This is allowing you to access members of the std namespace without resolving the scope.  Therefore...

std::string == string